# Inspect URL path in Google Search Console

Tags: google-developers-console, google-crawlers

Is there a way I can inspect URL in Google Search Console through direct link?  Currently I open my site through such link: https://search.google.com/search-console?resource_id=https://example.com/

Then I paste the url https://example.com/newpage.php in the upper box.

There used to be a way to direct link for that page, something like: https://search.google.com/search-console?resource_id=https://example.com/&url=https://example.com/newpage.php

But that's not working anymore.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is slightly off topic, however, I will answer your question and then offer my own recommendation for best practice usage.

Currently, what you want to do can be achieved by entering your desired parameters directly into your query string. The problem with this, as you've noticed, is that if Google changes their URL conventions, your link will stop working.

```
https://search.google.com/search-console/performance/search-analytics?resource_id=sc-domain%3Aexample.com&breakdown=page&metrics=CLICKS%2CIMPRESSIONS%2CPOSITION&page=!https%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&num_of_months=3
```

Search Console now supports the use of Regex (Re2). While it will require an additional step this will be more consistent for you.

1. Bookmark the GSC URL: https://search.google.com/search-console
2. Go to your desired property, click performance, create a new filter and select "Custom (Regex)", then insert your expression.

These will get you started:

```
Matches URL slug
^[foo]+(?:-[bar]+)*$

All urls within /page 
(http|https):\/\/www.example.com\/foo\/.*

All urls between a certain slug and ending
(http|https):\/\/www.example.com\/foo\/[^\/]+\/bar
```

Hopefully this helps (albeit a year later).